# Node has not been attached to a view in `PropsAnimatedNode.updateView`

Tags: android, react-native

Sometimes I can see this message but only in android, I think it comes out every time an alert is displayed.

```
Alert.alert('Oops!', this.props.user.errorMessage,
     [{
        text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('here press');
     }]);
```

The error is:

[image]

Anyone have any idea that may be causing this problem?

thanks

**RELATED**

[github Issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12893)

Answer (score 3):

As I've commented in the Github Issue that you linked, your error is probably due to the fact that you're trying to call `mapStateToProps` with a key that doesn't exist. Obviously, this is just an hypothesis, as we would certainly need more info regarding your project. Do you use redux? Which react-native version are you running? Where does `this.props.user.errorMessage` come from? Is that prop from a parent component or from a reducer?

Also, another possibility is that in the other tab you're importing some module that doesn't exist, or that isn't exported correctly.

BTW, I'm leaving this other solved issue here for reference: [#438](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/438)

I really hope this can be helpful to you man!

Comment: I'm using redux, React version: `0.39`, ...... `this.props.user.errorMessage` is a simple state inside `user` Store, changed using a redux action when my `ws` return me errors.